# font-url is resulting in asset prefix appearing twice in request for asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, sass, ruby-on-rails-5

In a Rails 5 application we are trying to load a custom font. In development this works as expected but in staging with asset prefix set to either `/static` or `static` it is resulting in a 404 for the font as it requests `/static/static/font_name`.

We are using Webpack to compile assets, we've tried removing the prefix and compiling everything to public assets but none of the items load correctly at that point. If we check the server the font has been fingerprinted and is in the `static` directory for the application.

SCSS file for fonts

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'neuzeits_book';
  src: font-url('neuzeits_book.eot');
  src: font-url('neuzeits_book.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       font-url('neuzeits_book.woff2') format('woff2'),
       font-url('neuzeits_book.woff') format('woff'),
       font-url('neuzeits_book.svg') format('svg'),
       font-url('neuzeits_book.ttf') format('truetype');
}

$font_body: 'neuzeits_book', arial;
```

The below is the generated css on staging.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'neuzeits_book';
    src: url(static/neuzeits_book-feb4879f32fd707ba88e9d1f9f2a5e901042ab66a3e01560d9b73f22ded85185.eot);
    src: url(static/neuzeits_book-feb4879f32fd707ba88e9d1f9f2a5e901042ab66a3e01560d9b73f22ded85185.eot#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(static/neuzeits_book-874e588d20dc28011a445eb8f645f610b6a312a7217bab344d1394187d96334a.woff2) format("woff2"),url(static/neuzeits_book-1228efc2d44dc6f54667fcba56588d3ad66c689b73e64f382370c23ebaa00975.woff) format("woff"),url(static/neuzeits_book-903eaa19a9dc9ae8210827ebf4591347271825b13bb4d25efb1fdacb1f8b9dab.svg) format("svg"),url(static/neuzeits_book-a34d20b4bf82e78b20547e4d32a4846acefc2e1f96e30ed9186a1b1594963d32.ttf) format("truetype")
}
```

And the below is the configuration for the assets on staging.

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
# config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
config.react.variant = :production

config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
config.assets.prefix = '/static'
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

Comment: Where do you placed the fonts? `app/assets/fonts` ?

Comment: @Pavan Yeah, that's the structure we've gone with

Comment: Check whether are there any directories that contains fonts and remove those.

Comment: The only directory with any fonts in the application is `app/assets/fonts` and `shared/public/static` on the staging server

Comment: Keep `app/assets/fonts` and remove `shared/public/static` files

Comment: @Pavan those are compiled by webpack though, it's where all the compiled assets are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152138/discussion-between-ryanmacg-and-pavan).

Comment: Ohh ok. I forgot you are using webpack.